# Xilinx VHDL Multicycle constraints

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I have some code that's running on a Xilinx Spartan 6, and it currently meets timing. However, I'd like to change it so that I use fewer registers.

```
signal response_ipv4_checksum     : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal response_ipv4_checksum_1   : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal response_ipv4_checksum_2   : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal response_ipv4_checksum_3   : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
…

process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        response_ipv4_checksum_3 <= utility.ones_complement_sum(x"4622",                  config.source_ip(31 downto 16));
        response_ipv4_checksum_2 <= utility.ones_complement_sum(response_ipv4_checksum_3, config.source_ip(15 downto 8));
        response_ipv4_checksum_1 <= utility.ones_complement_sum(response_ipv4_checksum_2, response_group(31 downto 16));
        response_ipv4_checksum   <= utility.ones_complement_sum(response_ipv4_checksum_1, response_group(15 downto 0));
    end if;
end process;
```

Currently, to meet timing, I need to split up the additions over multiple cycles. However, I have 20 cycles to actually compute this value, during which time the config value can't change.

Is there some attribute I can use (preferred) or line in the constraints (ucf) file that I can use so that I could simply write the same thing, but use no registers?

*Just for a bit of extra code, in my UCF, I already have a timespec that looks like this:*

```
NET pin_phy_rxclk TNM_NET = "PIN_PHY_RXCLK";
TIMESPEC "TS_PIN_PHY_RXCLK" = PERIOD "PIN_PHY_RXCLK" 8ns HIGH 50%;
```

Comment: Have you read about multicycle path constraints in the Xilinx Constraints Guide (cgd.pdf)?

Comment: I have. In the 12.1 Version, I wasn't able to see how I could convert their example to apply to code like this, and it appears that the multicycle section has been removed from the 14.2 version of cgd.pdf

Comment: Why do you need to reduce the number of registers - are you running out of them?  (I usually run out of LUTs first!)

Comment: @MartinThompson: This is more for my personal knowledge. I haven't run out of resources yet. I also wonder if doing things like this would enable the map and par stage to finish quicker (since it would have more freedom to place the adders).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a FROM:TO constraint:

```
TIMESPEC TSname=FROM “group1” TO “group2” value;
```

where `value` can be based on another timespec, like `TS_CLK*4`

So you'd adjust your process to only have flipflops on the output signals, create a timegroup with the inputs in it, another with the outputs in it, and use those for `group1` and `group2` .

So, group 1 would contain all the input nets `/path/to/your/instance/config.source_ip` and `/path/to/your/instance/response_group`.  It might be easier to create a vector input to the entity and wire up the config/response_group signals outside of it.  Then you can just use `/path/to/your/instance/name_of_input_signals`.

Group 2 would contain `/path/to/your/instance/response_ipv4_checksum`.

And, as you comment, you can use `TS_PIN_PHY_RXCLK*4` (assuming it is a time, not a frequency - otherwise you have to do a `/4` I think)

Comment: Hi Martin, So I've added a timespec from my ucf to the question. In this case, `TS_PIN_PHY_RXCLK`. So in your constraint, I could do value as `TS_PIN_PHY_RXCLK*4`. What would the contents of `group1` and `group2` be? I don't think I follow that part. And thanks for helping!